# How to find determinant of matrix using python

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

New at python and rusty on linear Algebra. However, I am looking for guidance on the correct way to create a determinant from a matrix in python without using Numpy. Please see the snippet of code below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
import math 
from math import sqrt
import numbers 
import operators

def determinant(self)

        if not self.is_square():
            raise(ValueError, "Cannot calculate determinant of non-square matrix.")
        if self.h > 2:
            raise(NotImplementedError, "Calculating determinant not implemented for matrices larger than 2x2.")


        |x| = A

    det(A) = [[A, B][C, D]]

    assert self.rows == A.cols
    assert self.row > 1
    term_list = []
```

Comment: This code makes no sense at all. You should start by reading some tutorials...

Comment: `from scipy.linalg import det,det([[1,2], [3, 4]])`

Comment: You want to look at `gaussian elimination` as this is commonly used to find the determinant of a squared matrix in computing. Here is another link which might be a good read. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/determinant-of-a-matrix/

Comment: @percusse he specifically asked for `without using Numpy. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` is an inbuilt function and cannot be used as a variable name. The code was not properly indented. This should work:

```py
def determinant(matrix, mul):

    width = len(matrix)
    if width == 1:
        return mul * matrix[0][0]
    else:
        sign = -1
        answer = 0
        for i in range(width):
            m = []
            for j in range(1, width):
                buff = []
                for k in range(width):
                    if k != i:
                        buff.append(matrix[j][k])
                m.append(buff)
            sign *= -1
            answer = answer + mul * determinant(m, sign * matrix[0][i])
    return answer

test_matrix = [[3,2,-3],[7,-1,0],[2,-4,5]]

print(determinant(test_matrix, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for your comments.

Comment: what does `mul` do?

Comment: Since `mul` appears to be used for the recursive call, but not something that the user is expected to know about, you could give it a default value. `def determinant(matrix, mul=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get the determinant of non square matrix. Maybe it is a non sense, but I found it useful this implementation in **`jupyter notebook`** because avoids the need of using `try` for the exceptions and sometimes it's interesting to get a zero output for a not square matrix.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[-2,-4]])
sp.Matrix(A)
```

[image]

```
B = np.hstack((A,np.array([[0],[0],[0]])))
sp.Matrix(B)
```

[image]

```
def determinant(A):
  if len(sp.Matrix(A).rref()[1]) < max(np.shape(A)):
    return 0
  else:
    return np.linalg.det(A)

determinant(A)
0
determinant(B)
0
np.linalg.det(A)  -----> ERROR
```