# Matrix determinant

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

I have this function to get determinant of matrix

```py
    def determinant(self) -> int:
        """
        Calculates the Determinant of matrix objects.
        Parameters
        ----------
        self
        Returns
        -------
        int
        Example
        -------
        >>> _matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
        >>> _matrix = Matrix(_matrix)
        >>> _matrix.determinant()
        0
        """
        if self.row != self.column:
            raise ValueError('Cannot get determinant of this matrix! Must be a square Matrix')
        else:
            def det(matrix):
                row = len(matrix)
                col = len(matrix[0])

                if (row, col) == (1, 1):
                    return matrix[0][0]

                # hard coding for 2x2
                elif (row, col) == (2, 2):
                    return matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]

                # using sarrus method to solve for 3x3, it's a little faster.
                elif (row, col) == (3, 3):
                    matrix1 = matrix[:]

                    # Extending matrix to use Sarrus Rule.
                    for i in range(row - 1):
                        _col = []
                        for j in range(col):
                            _col.append(matrix1[i][j])
                        matrix1.append(_col)

                    # Calculating Determinant
                    # Adding part
                    add_pointers = [(i, i) for i in range(row)]
                    result = 0
                    for pointer in range(row):
                        temp = 1
                        for tup in add_pointers:
                            i, j = tup
                            temp *= matrix1[i + pointer][j]
                        result += temp

                    # Subtracting part
                    sub_pointers = [((row - 1) - i, 0 + i) for i in range(row)]
                    for pointers in range(row):
                        temp = 1
                        for tup in sub_pointers:
                            i, j = tup
                            temp *= matrix1[i + pointers][j]
                        result -= temp
                    return result

                else:
                    sign = -1
                    result = 0
                    row1 = [matrix[0][i] * (sign ** i) for i in range(col)]
                    for x, y in enumerate(row1):
                        mat = matrix[:][1:]
                        sub_matrix = [[mat[i][j] for j in range(col) if j != x] for i in range(row - 1)]
                        result += y * det(sub_matrix)
                    return result

            return det(self.matrix)
```

i have hard-coded determinant of `2x2` and `3x3` matrix, then im recusing through the rest

as u can see its using recursion of `nxn` matrix(s)... i'm sure there is a faster way, this is extremely slow
A python implementation of the method would be recommended, thank you

Comment: [This](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html)?

Comment: If you are really interested in writing a faster function, then the main issue is not whether you use a loop or recursion or whatnot, but what algorithm you use. The most classic trick to efficiently compute a determinant is to first factor the matrix into a product of "nice" matrices. For instance, the determinant of a triangular matrix is simply the product of the elements of the diagonal, which is much much faster to compute than using your general formula. If you can write your matrix as a product of triangular matrices, suddenly computing the determinant will be very very fast.

Comment: For instance, scipy's determinant function uses ["LU decomposition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition): it factors the matrix M into a product M = P . L . U, where P is a permutation matrix, L is a lower-triangular matrix, and U is an upper-triangular matrix. Then computing the determinants of P, L and U is super fast.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the info

Comment: A python implementation for LU decomposition can be found on rosettacode.org, but I encourage you to try to write your own instead (there is nothing to be learned from copying someone else's implementation).

Answer (score -1):

The most common best ways would be either `list comprehension` or the `numpy` module.

**Reason**: The `for loops` will almost certainly be slower than a numpy array simply because of the contiguous and homogeneous nature of a numpy array. In simple terms `numpy` is basically one memory block all of the same type, where as a `list` points to different memory blocks and can contain any type.

Here is the numpy example (for 2d):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
result = np.linalg.det(a)


print(result)
```

One of the comments already (correctly) points to this:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

For more general larger m*n matricies, the advantages would be significant.

Comment: i would not like to use numpy, i wanna know how to do it in pure python

Comment: ...then you would use `list comprehension`, but please see the **reason** that i have just added. In particular, libraries like `numpy` are one of the biggest advantages of python.

Comment: here is an alternative (pure python) method:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47465356/how-to-find-determinant-of-matrix-using-python,  and it is left as an excercise for the reader to compare speeds of the two methods.

Comment: the `pure python` example u showed is the same thing i did... (pretty much)

Answer (score -1):

##### Find determinant for 3x3 matrix using the first row:

```py
"""
M:
    M11 M12 M13
    M21 M22 M23
    M31 M32 M33

detM:
    M11 * det2D([ [M22, M23], [M32, M33] ]) - 
    M12 * det2D([ [M21, M23], [M31, M33] ]) + 
    M13 * det2D([ [M21, M22], [M31, M32] ])    
"""

import numpy as np

def det3D(M):
    a = M[0][0] * det2D(np.array([ [ M[1][1],M[1][2] ], [ M[2][1],M[2][2] ] ]))
    b = M[0][1] * det2D(np.array([ [ M[1][0],M[1][2] ], [ M[2][0],M[2][2] ] ]))
    c = M[0][2] * det2D(np.array([ [ M[1][0],M[1][1] ], [ M[2][0],M[2][1] ] ]))
    return a - b + c


def det2D(M):
    return M[0][0]*M[1,1] - M[0][1] * M[1][0]


M = [ [1,0,0], [0,2,2], [0,2,4] ]
A = det3D(M)
B = round(np.linalg.det(M))
print(A)
print(B)
print(A == B)
```

##### Output:

```sh
4
4
True
```

Comment: But what if the matrix has 4 rows and 4 columns?

Comment: Using the first row, you find the 3x3 matrices determinants and linear combine them (`a - b + c  - d`). 
Find the recursion approach on my new comment, work on any NxN matrix.

Answer (score -1):

##### Find determinant of NxN Matrix using recursion:

Note: there are two methods for finding determinants, `smartDetNxN` run >35X faster than `detNxN` in the best case on a large matrix.

```py
import numpy as np

# compute partial determinant terms
def terms(M, col = 1, row = 1):
    return [x[:col-1] + x[col:] for x in M[0:row-1] + M[row:]]

# compute determinant using first row
def detNxN(M):
    N = len(M[0])
    # Recursion Base: 2x2 determenant
    if (N == 2): 
        M = np.array(M)
        return M[0][0] * M[1,1] - M[0][1] * M[1][0]
    # Recursion Loop
    else: 
        rowValues = M[:1][0]
        colsSigns = [1 if (col % 2 == 0) else -1 for col in range(N)]
        colsDets = [detNxN(terms(M, col + 1)) for col in range(N)]
        return sum([rowValues[col] * colsSigns[col] * colsDets[col] for col in range(N)])

# compute determinant using optimum row while skipping zero value columns
def smartDetNxN(M):
    N = len(M[0])
    # Recursion Base: 2x2 determenant
    if (N == 2): 
        M = np.array(M)
        return M[0][0] * M[1,1] - M[0][1] * M[1][0]
    # Recursion Loop
    else: 
        # find optimun row
        flatM = [len(np.flatnonzero(x)) for x in M]
        row = flatM.index(min(flatM))
        rowSign = 1 if (row % 2 == 0) else -1
        rowValues = M[row]
        # compute partial determinants
        colsSigns = [1 if (col % 2 == 0) else -1 for col in range(N)]
        colsDets = [smartDetNxN(terms(M, col + 1, row + 1)) if (rowValues[col] != 0) else 0 for col in range(N)]
        return sum([rowValues[col] * rowSign * colsSigns[col] * colsDets[col] for col in range(N)])

# test case for matrix
def testCase(M):
    print()
    N1 = len(M[0])
    N2 = len(M[0])
    A = smartDetNxN(M)
    B = round(np.linalg.det(M))
    print("Matrix %ix%i:" % (N1, N2))
    print("Actual detM = %d, Expected detM = %d " % (A, B))
    print("Test Pass:", A == B)

# main
def main():   
    # Matrix 2 x 2
    M1 = [[1,2,],[0,1]] 
    testCase(M1)
    
    # Matrix 3 x 3
    M2 = [[1,2,3],[2,1,2],[3,2,1]]
    testCase(M2)
    
    # Matrix 4 x 4
    M3 = [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,0,3], [3,0,1,2], [4,0,0,1]]
    testCase(M3)
    
    # Matrix 10 x 10
    M4 = [
        [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
        [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8],
        [2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,7],
        [3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,6],
        [4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,5],
        [5,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4],
        [6,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3],
        [7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2],
        [8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
        [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ]
    testCase(M4)
main()
```

##### Output:

```sh
Matrix 2x2:
Actual detM = 1, Expected detM = 1 
Test Pass: True

Matrix 3x3:
Actual detM = 8, Expected detM = 8 
Test Pass: True

Matrix 4x4:
Actual detM = 20, Expected detM = 20 
Test Pass: True

Matrix 10x10:
Actual detM = 999, Expected detM = 999 
Test Pass: True
```